# Не объявляется объекты в main.cpp n1 и n2 типа Number: no matching function for call to 'Number::Number()'

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

В main.cpp

```
#include "class_number.hpp"
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
   Number n1;
   Number n2;

}
```

В class_number.cpp

```
#include "class_number.hpp"
//конструктор по умолчанию
 Number::Number(double a, double b)
{
    a_ = new double(a);
    b_ = new double(b);
}
//конструктор копирования
Number::Number(const Number &other)
{
    a_ = new double(*other.a_);
    b_ = new double (* other.b_);
}
//деструктор
Number::~Number()
{
    delete a_;
    delete b_;
}
Number Number :: operator + (Number& add)
{
    double real = *a_+ *add.a_;
    double img = *b_+ *add.b_;
    return Number (real, img);
}
Number Number ::operator - (Number& sub)
{
    double real = *a_ - *sub.a_;
    double img = *b_ - *sub.b_;
    return Number (real, img);
}
Number& Number:: operator = (Number& num)
{
    *a_ = *num.a_;
    *b_ = *num.b_;

    return *this;
}
```

В class_number.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number{
double* a_;
double* b_;
public:
    Number (double a, double b);// конструктор по умолчанию
    Number(const Number& n); //конструктор копированя
   ~Number();//деструктор
   Number operator + (Number& add);
   Number operator - (Number& sub);
   Number& operator = (Number& num);
};
```

Comment: Что, вот прямо так и написано — `Number (//double a, double b);// конструктор по умолчанию`? И компилируется?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструктор **по умолчанию** — это конструктор **без** аргументов, а не тот, возле которого написан комментарий "*конструктор по умолчанию*". Где у вас такой?...

Если бы вы хотя бы вместо

```
Number (//double a, double b);// конструктор по умолчанию
```

написали

```
Number (double a = 0.0, double b = 0.0);
```

все было бы совсем иначе...

Кстати, использовать для двух `double` два `new double` — это уже издевательство. Занимает куда больше памяти, куда медленнее работает... Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: да прошу прощения, когда искала ошибку комментировала код, чтобы понять примерно в каком месте может быть ошибка, поэтому так перенеслось, спасибо большое))